# Maximum execution time exceeded while upgrading network on multisite local install

Tags: upgrade

Every time I try to hit "upgrade network" on my multisite install's dashboard I end up getting the following error message:

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in D:\...\www\wordpress\wp-includes\class-http.php on line 1595
```

Any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: What is on D:\...\www\wordpress\wp-includes\class-http.php on line 1595?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You network upgrade is taking too long to execute. You could mitigate the error by extending the execution time limit:

1. Increase `max_execution_time` in *php.ini*
2. Set `max_execution_time` in script to a higher number `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);`
3. Temporarily add this line in *index.php* `set_time_limit(0);`